# Problem deleting S3 objects using python and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am working to delete unneeded files from an AWS S3 bucket before transitioning it to long term Glacier storage.  I am running the following script using `Python` and `boto3`:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3.Bucket(<mybucketname>)

for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    if '.DS_S' in obj.key or '.ini' in obj.key:
        item_obj = s3.Object(obj.bucket_name, obj.key)
        print(obj.key, item_obj.content_length)
        del_resp = item_obj.delete()
        print("Delete response for", obj.key, "is\n", del_resp)
```

According to the [documentation here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.delete) - the `delete` method is supposed to return with a dict of 3 results - but here is an example of the response I see from one of the calls - and it is not what is in the documentation:

> > camera pics/Digi Pics/Camera 06-08/.DS_Store 24580
> >     Delete response for camera pics/Digi Pics/Camera 06-08/.DS_Store is
> >      {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '3B5CA1A9B0766A6B', 'HostId': 'HDWyoQg+RNrRZRC3nvqD8kR4bKDuMkTqDf7a7gGSD0lRUvucg56W76hG0+VP8BZ04oq+INsQUIY=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 204, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'HDWyoQg+RNrRZRC3nvqD8kR4bKDuMkTqDf7a7gGSD0lRUvucg56W76hG0+VP8BZ04oq+INsQUIY=', 'x-amz-request-id': '3B5CA1A9B0766A6B', 'date': 'Thu, 07 Feb 2019 16:00:26 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

The response has a http response of 204 - so it appears to have been successful in some way - but when I look in the S3 bucket - the file has not been deleted.  I don't receive any Python error codes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the original code worked - but AWS S3 took some time to actually do the deletes - I can't interpret what I am seeing any other way.  The files I wanted gone are now gone.

Comment: How long did it take approx.?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `item_obj = s3.Object(obj.bucket_name, obj.key)` create a new object?  So you aren't deleting the original, just copying and deleting the copy?

On `.object()` from : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html

> Sub-resources are methods that create a new instance of a child
>   resource. This resource's identifiers get passed along to the child.
>   For more information about sub-resources refer to the [Resources
>   Introduction Guide.](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html#subresources-intro)

Comment: You're making a good point about Python and being aware of when you're using an object or a copy of the object.

Comment: But I now think my mistake was thinking the delete operations would happen immediately.  I made some changes to the code in line with your suggestion - but this time none of the files I want to delete are there - both as seen by the code and confirmed by doing some searches in the AWS Management console.  So it seems the original code worked - S3 just takes time to actually do deletes.